# FreeTDS Connector - SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Tags: sql-server, freetds, unixodbc

I'm facing an issue in API call due to DB connection failure. We have tried for concurrent 90 calls to fetch some details based on some code which got failed in 1 percentage due to DB connection failure. Here is the  error message “SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)” while connecting to the DB. There are so many failures happening recently in API call due to the DB connection failure.

Is there any work around or permanent fix for this issue?

Some info,

## rpm -qa | grep freetds

> freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 freetds-devel-0.91-2.el6.x86_64

## tsql -C

> Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
>                               Version: freetds v0.91
>                freetds.conf directory: /etc
>        MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
>           Sybase binary compatibility: yes
>                         Thread safety: yes
>                         iconv library: yes
>                           TDS version: 4.2
>                                 iODBC: no
>                              unixodbc: yes
>                 SSPI "trusted" logins: no
>                              Kerberos: yes

Please give your hands to fix this issue.

Comment: If it only failing 1% of the time, it sounds like it might be more of an issue with your network than with SQL Server of FreeTDS. Either way, we'll need a lot more information to help diagnose. What's your network set up? What version of SQL Server? How are you attempting to connect? What TDS_Version are you using in your connection?

Comment: @FlipperPA : Thanks for the prompt reply. As this application is hosted on Azure cloud we are using their network. MySQL Server - 2012R2 and application is developed with PHP and connect using freetds. TDS Verssion - 7.0